# I'm trying to create a "command" for command prompt that creates a random number

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal

My code is

> ```
>    IF "%1" == "-?" (
> start randomhelp.bat
> )    IF NOT DEFINED %1 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
> IF NOT DEFINED %2 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
> IF NOT DEFINED %3 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
> set %1=0
> set /a heh=%random% * (%3 - %2 + 1) / 32768 + %2
> setx %1=%heh%
> ) )
> :notdefined
> ```

However whenever I try to run it is says / was unexpected at this time, however I do not have a / in it except for in the equation. What I'm trying to do is make it so when you type in something like

> random randomvalue 1 50

it will set the enviromental variable randomvalue to a random number between 1 and 50. Please help, I have no idea what is wrong with it. Sorry if this seems hard to understand.

Comment: You have set /a heh=, did you intend to have the /a there?

Comment: @IrishGeek82: yes, the `/a` has to be there to do the arithmetis instead of setting the variable just to the string (see `set /?`)

Comment: The basic problem is that the closing `)` in your `set`command is interpreted as the closing `)` of the `if`statement. So `/` is interpreted as the next command - and of course fails. Rafaels answer uses the set command outside of any `if`blocks, Adils answer uses enclosing `"` with the `set`command to tell the parser that the whole thing belongs to the `set`.

Comment: You don't have to check for the existence of all three parameters. If the third exists, the first two can't be empty. Just check for `%3`. if it exists, you know that `%1`and `%2` must also exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

    :: check for help request
    if "%~1"=="-?"  goto :showHelp

    :: check if we have at least three arguments
    if "%~3"==""    goto :notDefined

    :: check if the second and third arguments are numeric.
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%~2") do goto :badArguments
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%~3") do goto :badArguments

    :: calculate the random value and assign it to exit variable
    set "%~1="
    set /a "%~1=(%random% %% (%~3 - %~2 + 1)) + %~2" 2>nul

    :: if variable does not contain any value, bad data has been
    :: feed into script
    if not defined %~1 goto :badArguments

    goto :eof

:showHelp
    echo Usage: %~n0 varName lowValue highValue
    goto :eof

:notDefined
    echo error: arguments missing
    goto :eof

:badArguments
    echo error: wrong data in arguments
    goto :eof
```

Comment: @tatatat0, they are not needed, but, have you tried to use them? Have you executed the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this code

```
IF "%1" == "-?" (
start randomhelp.bat)
IF "%1" == "" (goto notdefined)
IF "%2" == "" (goto notdefined)
IF "%3" == "" (goto notdefined)
set /a heh=%random% * (%3 - %2 + 1)
set /a heh=heh / 32768 + %2
:notdefined
```

Tip: Arguments are not allowed to be modified, so `set %1=0` isn't valid.

Comment: `set %1=0` does not try to set `%1`. `%1` is parsed (`randomvalue` in this case), so it is executed as `set randomvalue=0`

Answer (score 0):

I like @Rafael's approach of writing that code as it avoids nested IFs. Anyway though, a couple of things to get it working:

```
REM You are missing the final parenthesis. Add that! 
REM Your second IF statement should be on another line. It could be b/c of copy/paste. 
REM Quote the whole expression to avoid that error

IF "%1" == "-?" (
start randomhelp.bat
)
IF NOT DEFINED %1 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
IF NOT DEFINED %2 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
IF NOT DEFINED %3 (goto notdefined) ELSE (
set %1=0
set /a "heh=%random% * (%3 - %2 + 1) / 32768 + %2"
setx %1=%heh%
)))
:notdefined
```